# Detecting text view change in Gtk and Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk

Beginner question.

I'm making a simple Gtk notepad in C# and MonoDevelop and everything works fine except one thing:

I want the program to detect if an opened file has been changed or not, so bascially I need it to detect any changes made to the Text View contents and when such a change happens to raise a global flag. But Text View doesn't seem to have any `change` event and those more specific, like `InsertAtCursor`, don't seem to work properly.

How can I detect if a change has been made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
bool changed = false;

txtEditor.Buffer.Changed += new EventHandler(onChangeEvent); 

public void onChangeEvent(object sender,EventArgs e)   {
  changed = true;
}
```